# Is it safe to access std::array data by address?

Tags: c++, arrays, dereference, stdarray

I would like to use bitwise data conversion on std::array objects and for this I need to know if it is safe to store the address of the array, or if there is a function that changes the data location. For example:

```
std::array<int, 100> array;
int* startMarker = array.data();
(filing the array and doing operations on it)
std::cout << *startMarker << std::endl;
```

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: `std::array` is basically a thin wrapper around classic C arrays. You can do anything you can do with a C array, plus everything you can do with a `std::vector` sans resize it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::array` is of static size and the addresses kept for the interned data elements are stable (unlike as with `std::vector`).

So yes, its safe to keep these addresses.